# Difference between executing a script with 'bash cd.sh' and 'source cd.sh'?

Tags: linux

Explain the difference between executing a script with `bash cd.sh` and `source cd.sh`

cd.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /tmp
```

Comment: One starts a new shell, one uses the current shell ?

Answer (score 0):

`bash` execute the script in a child shell that cannot modify the environment of the invoking shell while `source` executes the script in the current shell:

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
export MY_NAME=chucksmash
echo $MY_NAME
```

Running test.sh:

```
chuck@precision:~$ bash test.sh
chucksmash
chuck@precision:~$ echo $MY_NAME

chuck@precision:~$ source test.sh
chucksmash
chuck@precision:~$ echo $MY_NAME
chucksmash
chuck@precision:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, commands that look like `source script.sh` (or `. script.sh`) run the script in the current shell, **regardless of the `#!` line**.

Therefore, if you have a script (named `script.sh` in this example):

```
#!/bin/bash
VALUE=1
cd /tmp
```

This would print nothing (because `VALUE` is null) and not change your directory (because the commands were executed in another instance of bash):

```
bash script.sh
echo $VALUE
```

This would print `1` and change your directory to `/tmp`:

```
source script.sh
echo $VALUE
```

If you instead had this script (named `script.py` in this example):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'Hello, world"
```

This would give a WEIRD bash error (because it tries to interpret it as a bash script):

```
source shell.py
```

This would *also *give a WEIRD bash error (because it tries to interpret it as a bash script):

```
bash shell.py
```

This would print `Hello, world`:

```
./shell.py # assuming the execute bit it set
```